# Crop or mask geographics

Tags: graphics, image-processing, geography, geographics

I am trying to crop a map drawn with `GeoGraphics`. The map consists of `Line` and `Polygon` objects imported with the `OSMImport` resource function.

Here is what it looks like uncropped:

```
osm = ResourceFunction["OSMImport"][GeoBoundsRegion[{{35.695217, 35.705217}, {139.756822, 139.766822}}]];

streets = Values[Line[Values[osm[["Nodes", #Nodes, "Position"]]]] & /@ 
Select[osm["Ways"], KeyExistsQ[#Tags, "highway"] &]];

GeoGraphics[streets, GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image]

Currently, the lines extend outside of the original `GeoBoundsRegion`:
[image]

I would like to have a final image where the objects shown do not extend outside of this region. If possible, I would also like to be able to do this for *arbitrary* shapes. For example, a rounded square, a star, or a circle:

[image]

Currently, the only solution I can think of is to convert the image to a raster and then apply a mask. But is there a way to do so directly with `GeoGraphics`? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Note: The images above only show streets, but the map may also contain polygons of buildings, bodies of water, etc.

Comment: To crop it use `GeoGraphics[streets, GeoBackground -> None, GeoRange -> {{35.695217, 35.705217}, {139.756822, 139.766822}}]`

Comment: The "Details" section of the [GeoRange docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRange.html) describes how to crop a circular or polygon region.